# How can I convert a CSV file into a list in Python and then write the list data to a new CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with some lines(couple row of text), and I am trying to make a list from the csv file and write a csv file with a "Text" header.

I am trying like this

```
import csv

crimefile = open('file_1.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefile)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
print(allRows)
```

It's output like that:

> [["Line a 9x9 inch baking dish with lightly greased foil or plastic wrap. Grease another piece of foil or plastic wrap to cover the top, and set aside.\nPlace 1/2 cup of water in the bowl of an electric mixer, and sprinkle gelatin on top of water to soak.\nWhile gelatin is soaking, combine 1/4 cup of water, corn syrup, and sugar in a saucepan,
> and bring to a boil over medium heat. Boil the mixture hard for 1 minute.\nPour the hot sugar mixture into the gelatin mixture and beat on high for 12 minutes with electric
> mixer, until the mixture is fluffy and forms stiff peaks. Add vanilla and peppermint extracts, and beat just until blended.\nPour the marshmallow mixture into the prepared baking dish, using a greased spatula to smooth the top of the candy. Cover the candy with the reserved greased foil or wrap, and press down lightly to seal the covering to the top of the candy.\nAllow the marshmallow candy to rest for 4 hours or overnight. Mix together cornstarch and confectioner's sugar in a shallow dish. Using oiled scissors or an oiled kitchen knife, cut the marshmallow candy into strips, then into 1 inch squares. Dredge the marshmallows lightly in the cornstarch mixture and store in an airtight container."]]

But i want like this:

> ['Line a 9x9 inch baking dish with lightly greased foil or plastic wrap', 'Grease another piece of foil or plastic wrap to cover the top', 'and set aside',
> 'Place 1/2 cup of water in the bowl of an electric mixer', 'and sprinkle gelatin on top of water to soak',
> 'While gelatin is soaking', 'combine 1/4 cup of water', 'corn syrup, and sugar in a saucepan', 'and bring to a boil over medium heat', 'Boil the mixture hard for 1 minute',
> 'Pour the hot sugar mixture into the gelatin mixture and beat on high for 12 minutes with electric mixer', 'until the mixture is fluffy and forms stiff peaks', 'Add vanilla and peppermint extracts', 'and beat just until blended']

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're input file isn't a CSV.  It looks like a text file that you want to read in and split on commas, periods, and newlines.  Please clarify.  You should provide the input file as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the text to be split by commas and new lines, but all in one list.

```
allRows = []
with open('file_1.csv', 'r') as crimefile:
    for line in crimefile:
        allRows += line.strip().split(',')
print(allRows)
```